# Loading Data with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have a Route that loads a dashboard component, and a sidebar with different links to this dashboard component I'm attempting to use useEffect to load the appropriate data from the backend when the component is loaded

```
const Dashboard = ({match}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const thing = useSelector(state => state.things)[match.params.id]

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    await dispatch(loadStuff(match.params.id))
    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [match]);

  return loading
     ? <div>Loading</div>
     : <div>{thing.name}</div>

}
```

This works well enough for the first load. However when I click the NavLink on the sidebar to change { match }, thing.name blows up. I would expect, since match is a dependency on useEffect, that it would restart the load cycle and everything would pause until the load is complete, instead it appears to try to render immediately and the API call is not made at all. If I remove thing.name, I see the api call is made and everything works.

I keep running into this, so I appear to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to predictably load data with redux when a component is mounted. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Isn't the useEffect dependency only `match.params.id` ?

Comment: Also, I think useEffect only does a shallow compare of dependencies, to test if they have changed.

Comment: Ive tried it with match and match.params.id with the same result

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped your component with withRouter of react router dom?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Dashboard = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const thing = useSelector(state => state.things)[match.params.id]

const fetchData = async () => {
  setLoading(true)
  await dispatch(loadStuff(match.params.id))
  setLoading(false)
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, [match.params.id]);

return loading
   ? <div>Loading</div>
   : <div>{thing.name}</div>
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

Use `match.params.id` in the `useEffect` as comparison of object(match) should not be done.

```
{} === {} /* will always be false and useEffect will be called every time 
             irrespective of match.params.id change. */
```

Comment: I tried these updates and still see the problem :-/

Comment: send your code for this component along with import and exports.